# $.ajax - cannot redirect after http headers have been sent

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I am running into the above error at random times and I haven't been able to find a solution for it.

```
       //MyPage.aspx
       //Reload Ajax function
       $.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnReloadAjax = function (oSettings, sNewSource, fnCallback) {
           if (typeof sNewSource != 'undefined') {
               oSettings.sAjaxSource = sNewSource;
           }
           this.oApi._fnProcessingDisplay(oSettings, true);
           var that = this;

           oSettings.fnServerData(oSettings.sAjaxSource, null, function(json) {
               /* Clear the old information from the table */
               that.oApi._fnClearTable(oSettings);

               /* Got the data - add it to the table */
               for (var i = 0; i < json.aaData.length; i++) {
                   that.oApi._fnAddData(oSettings, json.aaData[i]);
               }

               oSettings.aiDisplay = oSettings.aiDisplayMaster.slice();
               that.fnDraw(that);
               that.oApi._fnProcessingDisplay(oSettings, false);

               /* Callback user function - for event handlers etc */
               if (typeof fnCallback == 'function') {
                   fnCallback(oSettings);
               }
           });
       };



//Timer
function AutoReload(){
 CheckInfoDate();
 setTimeout(function(){AutoReload();}, 50000);
}

function CheckInfoDate(){
   $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "MyPage.aspx/CheckDate",
               contentType: "application/json; chartset=utf-8",
               dataType: "json",
               success: function (data) { ProcessResult(data.d); },
               error: function (orjRequest){ ErrorHandler(); }
         });
       }

      function ErrorHandler() {
           window.location.href = "../Login.aspx";
       }

       function ProcessResult(result) {
           if (result != "False") {
               RefreshDataTable();
           }
       }

      function RefreshDataTable() {
               table1.fnReloadAjax();
       }

//MyPage.aspx.cs
[WebMethod(Description="Read Date from Database")]
public static String CheckDate()
{
  //Basic SQL read from database and return as string
  return DBCustomClass.CheckInfoDate().ToString();
}
```

The error log that I am receiving is:

> Source:
>   http ://localhost:8080/MyPage.aspx/CheckDate
>   System.Web.HttpException: Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been
>   sent.
>   at System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect(String url, Boolean
>   endResponse)
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you doing Response.Redirect anywhere?

Comment: I am not using Response.Redirect at all on the page. Basically, what I am trying to achieve is to use ajax to ping the server every 50 seconds to check if a date inside database has changed (new data).

`function ProcessResult(result) {
               //If Data not current - refresh grid
               if (result != "False") {
                   //showLoading();
                   hidePopup();
                   RefreshTable();
               }
           }
`
if a 'new' data is available, then it is retrieved from the database.

Comment: Then the issue is with the refresh of the grid most likely. You should post the code to `ProcessResult()` method, while at it post the `ErrorHandler()`. You should change your `dataType` to 'text' instead of 'json' when u return a static string.

Comment: @Dejan.S: I have updated the original posting with more code segments. I am using JQuery DataTables. http://www.datatables.net.
Based on the error log, it seems like the error is triggered from the $.ajax (CheckDate method) rather than the grid update itself; unless if I overlooked something. The biggest issue is that it is extremely difficult (close to impossible) to replicate this issue.

Comment: New Findings: The errors occurs only when the session times out. For example, the page will constantly send an ajax ping every 50 seconds. The site has a session time out setting of 2 hours. When the user navigates to the page and left it idle (exceeding the time out period), the error will be triggered. Hence, my conjecture is that when the first 'ajax - ping' is sent after the session times out, 2 response are sent back for the one request. First, is the response from the ajax call and the second is the time out message sent from the server. I suspect this is the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although recurrence is rare but other time is consistent ( but unreproducible ). I will mark this issue as resolved.